# Custom user-data reservation in ansi-c

Tags: c

I have a library with the following structure:

```
struct frame_meta_data
{
    uint8_t id;
    uint8_t general_field_1;
    uint8_t general_field_2;
    ...
    uint8_t user_data[16];
};
```

And I would like users of the library to be able to save custom data into frame objects (that's what the **user_data** field is for).

However when trying to cast user_data into a custom structure:

```
frame_meta_data cur_frame;
...
#define USER_HDR ((struct my_user_header*)cur_frame.user_data)
```

I get the following error:

```
warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
#define USER_HDR ((struct my_user_header*)cur_frame.user_data)
```

How can I work around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't cast. Use `memcpy`.

Comment: @melpomene it will hurt my performance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinterpreting addresses like that isn't allowed by the C standard. Strict aliasing means that compilers are free to assume two pointers of different types will never point at the same object, and then make all sorts of optimizations based of that.

Your code violates the C standard and has undefined behavior on account of that. But you can fix it still. Like **melpomene** suggested in the comments, don't cast, but use `memcpy`:

```
struct my_user_header obj;
memcpy(&obj, cur_frame.user_data, sizeof obj);
```

Alternatively, some compilers allow you to write non-standard code with compiler option, such as GCC's `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what you are doing, you can disable that warning. There is however a potential problem.

Assume that the structure you want to use contains something that is larger than 1 byte. For example a 4-byte integer. Now if you simply cast that user_data field to your structure it is possible that the int is not aligned to 4-byte boundary as it should be. This might result in a runtime exception in some architectures.

Using `memcpy` should solve that problem though. And remove the warning.

Comment: Will it still be so if user_data is aligned to 4?

Comment: You won't have any problems with 4-byte types if user_data is aligned to 4, but you might have problems with 8-byte types.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's because you're involving copies of this `USR_DATA` macro expression in multiple accesses to the data area, and it's confusing the compiler. Or perhaps you're even mixing `USR_DATA` accesses with manipulations of the underlying `char` array.

If the data area is only being initialized and accessed as that given user data type, there isn't any aliasing going on. Ensure you use it that way.

I would provide an external (as in, non-inlined, external linkage) API function which, given a frame object, returns a `void *` to the associated user data:

```
struct foobar *fbs = (struct foobar *) frame_get_userdata(fr);

// now work just with fbs
```

The cast isn't necessary; that's my style.

Depending on what precedes the user data, it might not be suitably aligned for arbitrary use. One easy way to fix that would be to make it the first `struct` member, if that option is available. Otherwise there are various fairly portable tricks involving making a union between a `char` array and various types like `long double` and whatnot, or else using compiler-specific constructs, like `__attribute__((aligned))` with GCC.